# JSON "undefined" when looking up CRM 2011 systemuserid

Tags: json, dynamics-crm-2011

The code (below beneath the JSON) evaluates the following JSON data and returns "undefined" even though it is clear that systemuserid is available.  Thanks in advance for helping.

```
    {
    "d" : {
    "results": [
    {
    "__metadata": {
    "uri": "http://dynamics/DynamicsCRM/xrmservices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/new_new_license_sys        temuserSet(guid'561d5751-0496-e111-84f8-0050561a2a63')", "type": "Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.new_new_license_systemuser"
    }, "new_new_license_systemuserId": "561d5751-0496-e111-84f8-0050561a2a63", "new_licenseid": "538e6567-8c95-e111-84f8-0050561a2a63", "systemuserid": "40dda08e-2ee5-e011-b843-0050561a2a63", "VersionNumber": null
    }
    ]
    }
    }

    $.ajax(
    {        type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            url: odataSelect,
            beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) 
                { XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); },
            success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest)
                    {            
                   ProcessReturnedEntity(data.d);
                    },
           error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    { alert('OData Select Failed: ' + odataSelect); 
                    }
    });

    ProcessReturnedEntity = function(OneEntity)
    {
    var one = OneEntity;
    var Userid = one.systemuserid;
    alert(Userid);
    }
```

Comment: Is it the alert with userid that that show undefined, or is it somewhere else in the code?

Answer (score 2):

Have you used the [internet explorer F12 Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to step into that line and inspect the variables involved? You mention "even though it is clear that systemuserid is available", if it is undefined, it is not available on that object, or perhaps that object itself is null for whatever reason.
Hope that helps.

Comment: I do not know why F12 is not launching the developer tools...  There must be a setting that I need to change.  I am an administrator...

Comment: Uh oh, is it possible you are on a verion of IE before IE 8?

Comment: I was able to get developer tools to work...  had to reset IE to default settings.

Answer (score 1):

From the `json` result posted i believe you should try to access the `systemuserid` like this:

```
 var Userid = one.results[0].systemuserid;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I tried your suggestions and am getting this error:Unable to get value of the property 'systemuserid': object is null or undefined

Comment: Can you post the whole JSON output returned by the ajax call and how are you retrieving data (the url)? If the entity you are trying to retrieve has a relation with systemuser than you should find the systemuserid having an EntityReference type in the JSON result returned.

Comment: The JSON (below)...  thanks for your help
{
"d" : {
"results": [
{
"__metadata": {
"uri": "http://dynamics/DynamicsCRM/xrmservices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/new_new_license_systemuserSet(guid'5f94a166-8ba0-e111-84f8-0050561a2a63')", "type": "Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.new_new_license_systemuser"
}, "new_new_license_systemuserId": "5f94a166-8ba0-e111-84f8-0050561a2a63", "new_licenseid": "33a4d804-0696-e111-84f8-0050561a2a63", "systemuserid": "40dda08e-2ee5-e011-b843-0050561a2a63", "VersionNumber": null
}
]
}
}